# Does Ad-Hoc re-distribution required for app before profile expiry

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have cordova based iOS app where till now i am distributing that app using ad-hoc method only to few number of people and my developer account will expire in September 2017. If i renew my developer account before September and do i require to again download the provisioning profiles and rebuild app and re distribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates comes with expiry. In General it is for 1 yr from date of creation. After which you have to recreate new every year.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah so if renew my account before expiry also i need to regenerate the profile from developer.apple.com and download it to my pc and import it to xcode regenerate the build ..

Comment: No just need to recreate adhoc certificate thats it

Comment: so just build app and distrubute

Comment: yes if you are sending build to testers. But if your app already in store then nothing. You will only need to do if you sending new build or uploading new version. Hope it is clear now :)

Comment: actually im distributing .ipa file to the people and im not putting in app store